# Вопрос обыденный:Решето Эратосфена. Не понятен лишь шаг 5: p^2<n

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Древний алгоритм «Решето Эратосфена» для поиска всех простых чисел до `n` выглядит так:

1.Создать список последовательных чисел от `2` до `n`: 2, 3, 4, ..., n.
2.Пусть `p=2`, это первое простое число.
3.Зачеркнуть все последующие числа в списке с разницей в `p`, т.е. `2*p`, `3*p`, `4*p` и т.д. В случае `p=2` это будут 4,6,8....
4.Поменять значение p на первое не зачеркнутое число после `p`.
5.Повторять шаги 3-4, пока `p2 < n`.
6.Все оставшиеся не зачеркнутыми числа – простые.

Данный код мне понятен,кроме шага 5.. почему `p^2`,для чего это нужно? Или стоит относиться к этому, как условию задания?

```
// шаг 1
var arr = [];

for (var i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
  arr[i] = true
}

// шаг 2
var p = 2;

do {
  // шаг 3
  for (i = 2 * p; i < 100; i += p) {
    arr[i] = false;
  }

  // шаг 4
  for (i = p + 1; i < 100; i++) {
    if (arr[i]) break;
  }

  p = i;
} while (p * p < 100); // шаг 5

// шаг 6 (готово)
// посчитать сумму
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i]) {
    sum += i;
  }
}

alert( sum );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну подумайте сами - какой смысл проверять на делимость на величину, большую квадратного корня?

Пусть `N = a*b`. Если `a > sqrt(N)`, то понятно, что `b < sqrt(N)` и вы проверите его раньше...

Например, 15. При проверке на делимость на 3 вы уже получите 5.

Так что все числа до 100, проверенные на делимость до 10, понятно, будут простыми - потому что если они делятся на что-то больше 10, то результат был бы меньше 10. Но такой результат - при проверке делителей до 10 - вы **уже** не получили.

Так понятно? Проверять делители больше корня - бессмысленно, просто лишняя работа (и много!) - вот мы от нее и избавляемся.